# How to insert a bracket between the specified alphabet (i.e. A, D, F, R) and the digit using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to insert a bracket between the specified alphabet (i.e. A, D, F, R) and the digit using regular expression?

input:

```
A1
F42
D3
R6
```

Expected output:

```
(A)1
(F)42
(D)3
(R)6
```

What I have tried:

```
let inputString="f42"
let expPattern=/[ADFR]\d{1,3}/ig;
 console.log(inputString.replace(expPattern,"(`$0`)"));
```

It returns "$0" only.

How can I implement the replacement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should enclose the alphabet and the digits in separate capture groups so you can reference them in the replacement string:

```js
let inputString="F42"
let expPattern=/([ADFR])(\d{1,3})/ig;
console.log(inputString.replace(expPattern,"($1)$2"));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the full match in the replacement, you can make use of a positive lookahead `(?=\d{1,3}\b)` asserting 1-3 digits to the right.

To prevent partial matches, you can use word boundaries `\b`

In the replacement use the full match denoted as `$&`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/W0nUFG/1) with all the replacements.

```js
let inputString="F42"
let expPattern=/\b[ADFR](?=\d{1,3}\b)/ig;
console.log(inputString.replace(expPattern,"($&)"));
```